# mysql root password is empty

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install mysql after i replaced my disk with MySQL on it with a bigger and faster one. After installing `mysql-server` on ubuntu, when running `select user,host,authentication_string from user where user='root';`, `authentication_string` is blank.

I set my password but the only way to login to root is to run the MySQL command with sudo and if I try to put the password in if I run `mysql -u root -p` it doesn't work. I have also tried to just leave the password blank when logging in and it has had no effect. Any help is greatly appreciated.

System info:
pop!_os amd64 20.04 (ubuntu like)

Comment: How did you set your password?

Comment: The root account may be configured to use socket authentication rather than password authentication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html and https://serverfault.com/a/795304/794142

Comment: @bob thanks, this works! would you mind adding an answer to the post so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Some installations default to enabling the MySQL (and MariaDB) [socket authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) plugin.

Rather than using password authentication it is sufficient to be logged in as `root` on the operating system (either by logging in directly as `root` or by using `sudo mysql` to elevate your privileges to root) to log in as `root` to the MySQL server. You can use the same mechanism for a regular users too, i.e. when I log in as `bob` to the Linux server and a `bob@llocalhost`  account exists in MySQL I can log on directly without additional authentication.

To remove socket authentication log in as root

```
$ sudo mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
```

Set up a root with a password instead of the socket authentication

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Activate these changes by flushing all cached credentials

```
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Then you can log in with `mysql -u root -p` and the new password you assigned.